# Adding multiple checkboxes in Drupal-form

Tags: php, forms, drupal, checkbox, drupal-7

I would like to add some checkboxes in my D7-form. For some reason, the snippet below isn't working. Any idea why or any advice how to do it properly?

```
$options = array('A', 'B', 'C');
foreach ($themas as $thema) {

        // Initialize array
        $ra = array();

        // Fill up the array with different keys
        $key = $prefix.'_thema_'.$thema->tid.'_fiche';
        $ra[$key]['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
        $ra[$key]['#name'] = $prefix.'_thema_'.$thema->tid.'_opties';
        $ra[$key]['#options'] = $options;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you're re-initialising `$ra` in every step of the loop so it will only ever contain one set of checkboxes. Try initialising it outside of the loop:

```
$options = array('A', 'B', 'C');

// Initialize array
$ra = array();

foreach ($themas as $thema) {
    // Fill up the array with different keys
    $key = $prefix.'_thema_'.$thema->tid.'_fiche';
    $ra[$key]['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
    $ra[$key]['#name'] = $prefix.'_thema_'.$thema->tid.'_opties';
    $ra[$key]['#options'] = $options;
}

$form['some_key'] = $ra;
```

Also make sure your `$prefix` string doesn't start with a `#` symbol or Drupal will consider it a property rather than an element that needs to be rendered.

Comment: It was indeed an initializing issue! The value `#options` got overwritten every time. Thanks